# Im have a <form> that i am posting in an INSERT INTO query and I need to be able to nest a query inside of a query?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, sql

My question is pretty confusing but here we go.  I a  that i am using to post data into the 'blogposts' table.  My problem arises for the last value of the query to be inserted is a picture(BLOB).  This data needs to be pulled from the users profile aka(another table).  So my question is, is there any way to have a SUBQUERY inside of the VALUES() statement in SQL to grab the profile pic of the account user?

Here is my code of the query that does not work:

```
<?php
    require_once('startsession.php');
    require_once('appvars.php');
    require_once('connectvars.php');

    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $sql="INSERT INTO blogposts (name, subject, message, post_time, profPic)
    VALUES
    ('$_SESSION[username]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[message]',current_timestamp,IN(SELECT picture
                                                                                    FROM player
                                                                                    WHERE user_id
                                                                                    EQUALS" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    $page='index.php';
    header('Location:'.$page);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Unipartisandev: There's nowhere else it could reasonably be put.

Comment: You're right, but I also just had an epiphany about the $_POST values.    Even if they were sanitized and passed again through hidden input fields someone could still come along and write their own form that sends those post values.

Comment: have you try your sql to directly execute (without PHP)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have the user ID so just store that instead of storing the same image (and username) multiple times in your database. You should read up on database normalization. I would actually not even store it once in the database, just in the file-system as a normal image. And you definitely need to read up on sql injection as well.

Comment: I was storing the image to use as a thumbnail when a comment is posted so it needs to be stored again to be read in with the comments.  That's why.

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['username']);
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['userid']);
$subject= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['subject']);
$message= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['message']);

$sql="INSERT INTO blogposts (name,subject,message,post_time,profPic)
SELECT '$username', 
 '$subject',  
 '$message', 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
 picture
  FROM player WHERE user_id = '$user_id';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

As mentioned in the comments, look into SQL Injection and the mysqli_real_escape_string function (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

EDIT: updated to include procedural style escape string and correct syntax

Comment: I will definately look into that thank you for the reply. Iam receiving an error though:

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EQUALS 1' at line 7

Comment: Also, prepare this statement and use parameter markers instead of variables.  When you execute the statement pass in the values.  This will prevent SQL injection. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone's replies.  Im new to SQL so this helped me a lot.